# How does JavaScript interpret indexing array with array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

```
[1,2,4,8][0,1,2,3]
// equals to 8 (the last element of the indexing array (3) becomes the index)
```

Why is this not a `SyntaxError` error (a bad legacy or a purposeful feature)? (A possible duplicate, however I wasn't able to find an answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections).)

**Update:** Why `the contents of the square brackets are treated as an expression`?

Answer (score 5):

The first part:

```
[1,2,4,8]
```

is interpreted as an array literal. The second part:

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

is interpreted as square bracket notation to access a member of the array. The contents of the square brackets are treated as an expression, which is seen as a sequence of comma separated values:

```
0,1,2,3 // or (0,1,2,3) as an independent expression
```

That expression returns the last value, so is effectively:

```
[1,2,4,8][3] // 8
```

Comment: Yes, this is obvious from the question, which is (apologies for asking again): `why is it like this?`.

Comment: @Vidul: because the syntax `x[y]` is actually interpreted as `reference[expression]`. Since the index is an expression, the comma is treated as an operator in the same way that a `+` or a `-` would be. The reason the index is an expression is to allow for things like: `x[y+1]`. That's why

Comment: @slebetman Your comment makes perfect sense. Would you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @Vidul: Unfortunately I can't as this question is closed and the duplicate one is not exactly asking what you are asking.

Comment: @Vidul: I don't mind anyway. At close to 40k I don't need the points